# Graph real valued functions of two variables without computational aid

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, graphing-functions, 3d, substitution

I am wondering about different methods for plotting real valued functions of two variables manually. So far I have encountered 2 methods:

1. Using contour maps and setting one of the variables to 0 and plotting the one dimensional graph of the other variable, and vise versa
2. Using a suitable variable substitution

I have not managed to find a clear explanation specifying a method of how one should go about drawing functions of two variables. Is method 1 the best way to go about it? And does method 2 always works?

For instance if one wants to graph the function $\textit{f}$(x, y)= ln($x^{2}$+$y^{2}$), both methods work and one can use the substitution $r^{2}$=$x^{2}$+$y^{2}$ which would give the function $\textit{f}$(r)= 2 ln r.

But what would be a suitable variable substitution for f(x,y)=x +2y -2? (which represents a plane)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Some packages (eg, Sage) can do interactive [3D plots](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxti8EKwjAQBe_5ikcvzdpV2ojH_EP7BaU2gkJxS1p18_eNIHjQ28DMKCPB4zlEWyqnkoz2Z3ncw5LFh7K3ytg7hiOGTZkbRkOmzWqeZD0Gq5XbpXfy-5Ppvl39r2DIPIy3Nfn6cGKMMkn0RbyEgsxylZdtUaGjDS9MM6k=&lang=sage).

Comment: @Moo Yes exactly, I mean without any computational aid, that is using a manual approach. I have specified it in the title now, thank you for pointing it out! It seems like the article discusses method 1, is that the preferred method, and not substitution?

Comment: Thank you for the answer!